# Symfony framework.yaml invalid YAML - but it's not?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I've started getting this error...not sure why or how?

Here is the framework.yaml:

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        ad_ldap:
            ldap:
                service: Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap
                base_dn: dc=mydomain,dc=local
                search_dn: 'appuser'
                search_password: "xxx"
                default_roles: ROLE_USER
                uid_key: 'sAMAccountName'
                filter: '({uid_key}={username})'
```

Giving me this error:

> In FileLoader.php line 180:
> The file "/vagrant/project/config/packages/security.yaml" does not
> contain valid YAML: Unexpected characters near "rname})'        " at
> line 12 (near "filter: '({uid_key}={us     ername})'        ") in
> /vagrant/project/config/packages/security.yaml (which is loaded in
> resource "/vagrant/project/config/packages/security.yaml").
>
> In YamlFileLoader.php line 693:
> The file "/vagrant/project/config/packages/security.yaml" does not
> contain valid YAML: Unexpected characters near "rname})'        " at
> line 12 (near "filter: '({uid_key}={us     ername})'        ").
>
> In Parser.php line 760:
> Unexpected characters near "rname})'        " at line 12 (near
> "filter: '({uid_key}={username})'        ").

Comment: Looks like the problem is in `framework.yaml` file, not in `.env`

Comment: Makes no sense...I added the framework.yaml snippet above. Nothing has changed in the YAML files for over a year...something updated during a deploy I think and the code is choking...

Comment: I commented out the ide and secret keys....now it's complaining about the LDAP configuration. Uggh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html#strings

the part:

> Strings containing any of the following characters must be quoted. Although you can use double quotes, for these characters it is more convenient to use single quotes, which avoids having to escape any backslash :

```
    :, {, }, [, ], ,, &, *, #, ?, |, -, <, >, =, !, %, @, `
```

Can you try quoting all strings there? (using single quotes)

Also, which Symfony version?

Comment: Your answer correctly indicates that only string with certain characters need to be quoted.  What exactly would quoting all strings accomplish? Just curious.

Comment: @Cerad exclude one possible reason of failure :) But anyway: im curious if it helped OP or not

Comment: I removed a couple of extra lines and that seems to have fixed the issue...frustrating as they've been there for over two years and now suddenly gave me issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a vendor issue with symfony and is corrected already but not released as of this writing.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/39229

Comment: I tried changing single to double quotes, etc. It was a couple of extra lines that I removed and that seems to have fixed the issue??? Symfony 4.4.17